# How to select from 2nd table if 1st table is empty in the midst of a joined subquery

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query that works fine as is. It pulls data from 12 monthly databases to generate a report. However, now we're going to import data twice per month instead of once per month and so I'm adding 12 more databases. One for the first half and one for the second half of the month. The database ending in "_A" is the first half and "_B" is the second half.  We want the 2nd half data if it's there. If not, we want the first half data. How can I modify my query to test for data in "_B" and select from "_A" if no data in "_B"?

I've tried using IF and CASE. I've googled but found nothing that addresses my scenario. Hoping someone who knows SQL a little better than me can help out.

Here's the current SQL that only pulls from the "_B" databases:

```
SELECT      JanAct.DDName, 
            JanAct.JanActual, 
            FebAct.FebActual, 
            MarAct.MarActual, 
            AprAct.AprActual, 
            MayAct.MayActual, 
            JunAct.JunActual, 
            JulAct.JulActual, 
            AugAct.AugActual, 
            SepAct.SepActual, 
            OctAct.OctActual, 
            NovAct.NovActual, 
            DecAct.DecActual
FROM       (SELECT DDName, [% Eff] AS JanActual FROM TIP_2_Jan_B.dbo.V_DDSum) AS JanAct
            FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT DDName, [% Eff] AS DecActual FROM TIP_2_Dec_B.dbo.V_DDSum) AS DecAct ON JanAct.DDName = DecAct.DDName
            FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT DDName, [% Eff] AS NovActual FROM TIP_2_Nov_B.dbo.V_DDSum) AS NovAct ON JanAct.DDName = NovAct.DDName 
            FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT DDName, [% Eff] AS OctActual FROM TIP_2_Oct_B.dbo.V_DDSum) AS OctAct ON JanAct.DDName = OctAct.DDName
            FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT DDName, [% Eff] AS SepActual FROM TIP_2_Sep_B.dbo.V_DDSum) AS SepAct ON JanAct.DDName = SepAct.DDName 
            FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT DDName, [% Eff] AS AugActual FROM TIP_2_Aug_B.dbo.V_DDSum) AS AugAct ON JanAct.DDName = AugAct.DDName 
            FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT DDName, [% Eff] AS JulActual FROM TIP_2_Jul_B.dbo.V_DDSum) AS JulAct ON JanAct.DDName = JulAct.DDName 
            FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT DDName, [% Eff] AS JunActual FROM TIP_2_Jun_B.dbo.V_DDSum) AS JunAct ON JanAct.DDName = JunAct.DDName 
            FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT DDName, [% Eff] AS MayActual FROM TIP_2_May_B.dbo.V_DDSum) AS MayAct ON JanAct.DDName = MayAct.DDName 
            FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT DDName, [% Eff] AS AprActual FROM TIP_2_Apr_B.dbo.V_DDSum) AS AprAct ON JanAct.DDName = AprAct.DDName 
            FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT DDName, [% Eff] AS FebActual FROM TIP_2_Feb_B.dbo.V_DDSum) AS FebAct ON JanAct.DDName = FebAct.DDName 
            FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT DDName, [% Eff] AS MarActual FROM TIP_2_Mar_B.dbo.V_DDSum) AS MarAct ON JanAct.DDName = MarAct.DDName
```

Comment: Why did you create 24 databases? 
And I think LEFT OUTER JOIN should be sufficient here.
Also I do not see the benefit of having subqueries.

Comment: I didn't create this, I inherited it. I don't have the time to rework it, I have to have it working for the bi-monthly  imports. So I just nail on 12 more databases for the mid-month pulls. I would have to re-write everything from the apps that pull the data and push it into these databases to the Web pages that display the reports. Just not enough time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By firstly creating a single dataset prioritizing and joining the data becomes very easy.

```
WITH data(DDName, [% Eff], [Period], [Source])
AS(
    -- A Database
    SELECT DDName, [% Eff], 'JanActual', 'A' FROM TIP_2_Jan_B.dbo.V_DDSum UNION ALL
    SELECT DDName, [% Eff], 'FebActual', 'A' FROM TIP_2_Feb_B.dbo.V_DDSum UNION ALL
    SELECT DDName, [% Eff], 'MarActual', 'A' FROM TIP_2_Mar_B.dbo.V_DDSum UNION ALL
    SELECT DDName, [% Eff], 'AprActual', 'A' FROM TIP_2_Apr_B.dbo.V_DDSum UNION ALL

    -- B databases
    SELECT DDName, [% Eff], 'JanActual', 'B' FROM TIP_2_Jan_B.dbo.V_DDSum UNION ALL
    SELECT DDName, [% Eff], 'FebActual', 'B' FROM TIP_2_Feb_B.dbo.V_DDSum UNION ALL
    SELECT DDName, [% Eff], 'MarActual', 'B' FROM TIP_2_Mar_B.dbo.V_DDSum UNION ALL
    SELECT DDName, [% Eff], 'AprActual', 'B' FROM TIP_2_Apr_B.dbo.V_DDSum
),
PrioritizedData AS(
    SELECT *, [Priority] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DDName, [% Eff], [Period] ORDER BY [Source] DESC)
    FROM data
),
SelectTopPrioData AS(
    SELECT * FROM PrioritizedData
    WHERE [Priority] = 1
)
SELECT * 
FROM SelectTopPrioData
PIVOT
(
    MAX([% Eff])
    FOR [Period] IN ([JanActual], [FebActual], [MarActual], [AprActual])
) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: Thanks. Will give it a try on monday.

Comment: This worked great after I changed the PARTITION BY to use only DDName. It was returning both A and B periods with Priority = 1 on everything. Thanks for the assist!

Comment: You're right, the `PARTITION BY` is wrong, you should only remove `[% Eff]` though. Both `DDName` and `[Period]` do need to be in there.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I also had to select ddname, [% eff], period from PrioritizedData   (instead of *) in order for the pivot to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this.

```
SELECT      JanAct.DDName, 
            ...
            DecActual = isnull(DecAct.DecActual, DecAct_A.DecActual)
FROM       (SELECT DDName, [% Eff] AS JanActual FROM TIP_2_Jan_B.dbo.V_DDSum) AS JanAct
            ...    
            FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT DDName, [% Eff] AS DecActual FROM TIP_2_Jan_A.dbo.V_DDSum) AS DecAct_A ON JanAct.DDName = DecAct_A.DDName
```

Comment: I'll try this on monday. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic SQL:

```
 declare @sel varchar(max)

set @sel = ' SELECT
         .......
         FROM         '

 if (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM   TTIP_2_Jan_B.dbo.V_DDSum)  =0
   begin
     set @sel = @sel+'SELECT DDName, [% Eff] AS DecActual FROM TIP_2_Jan_A.dbo.V_DDSum'
   END
   ELSE 
   BEGIN
    set @sel = @sel+'SELECT DDName, [% Eff] AS DecActual FROM TIP_2_Jan_B.dbo.V_DDSum'
END

exec(@sel)
```

Comment: even that that this is a good Answer can you explain a bit what you are doing here